# ASP.NET MVC 3 with ExtJS returning wrong json

Tags: javascript, .net, json, asp.net-mvc-3, extjs

Here's my return code:

```
return Json(new { success = success, message = message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

And i always get a "(" and "pre" tag before and after the json (stackoverflow does not allow me to write the tag pre directly).

Im using ExtJS to send the request, anyone can help?

Comment: are you returning a JsonResult?

Comment: Yes. Trying aonther content types too, but nothing :(

Comment: Can you post the code from your View where you are calling this?

Comment: Thanks Mike, Jairo answer my question! Thanks for interest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look a this post, here is the reason of the pre tag.

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?17248-lt-pre-gt-json-lt-pre-gt-in-File-upload-response-(FF-only)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what im looking for!

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?17248-lt-pre-gt-json-lt-pre-gt-in-File-upload-response-%28FF-only